How to open "send this server message to my contacts" menu in telegram mini app
Good afternoon, i now working on telegram mini app project, and cant find way to open send message menu in that telegram app. User press button, then he see his contats, choose one and send to that contant message from server.
I will be very glad if someone can provide information about method or any other way to implement it, thanks to everyone who read.
